# GJS: global.window_manager.get_workspaces() is undefined

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I have a code like this for my extension

`for (let i = 0; i < screen.get_n_workspaces(); ++i) {
   let w = screen.get_workspace_by_index(i);
   //Do something
}`

Since gjs maps c functions to javascript, `meta_screen_get_n_workspaces` become `get_n_workspaces`. However when I try this for `meta_screen_get_workspaces`

`screen.get_workspaces().forEach(w => {
   //Do someting
})`

it says 'get_workspaces is not a function'. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are relying on an API that was recently changed in libmutter. If you are using an older version of libmutter or newer version than the date of the change, you made need to do a check for the global variable.

You can probably figure out from [the diff in Gnome Shell](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/commit/47ea10b7c976abb1b9ab4f34da87abb1e36855fe#diff-6b6b2ef981951428e4f32fbe306acb60) how your code needs to be adjusted.

Generally, workspaces are now handled by `MetaWorkspaceManager`, which is available in Gnome Shell as `global.workspace_manager` and you can call `get_n_workspaces()` on that. The related upstream file in libmutter is [`workspace_manager.h`](https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/blob/master/src/meta/meta-workspace-manager.h). Before that I believe they were accessed through `global.screen`.

Comment: Thanks that helped me. However I rely on `MetaScreen`'s 'size-changed' signal in my extension. What is the equivalent of this thing on newer versions if it will be removed completely?

Comment: I think in this case you should just use Gdk's Screen and Display objects. `Gdk.Screen.get_default().connect('size-changed', () => {})`. I believe `global.screen` was just a convenience for that anyways.